# Total sum depending on select, qnty & radio choice

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am 16. I make such interesting handmade things a lot, and recently people are asking me to sell it to them, so I decided to make a small site with the order form there for selling my handmade things...

So, I need your help. I have searched a lot on it, tried it, but as I am no longer straight, my tryings were useless...

Here is what I am going to have:

```css
.selectProduct{display:block;}
.selectShippingMethod{display:block;margin:10px 0;}
.total{display:block;margin:10px 0;font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">

<form class="order">

<div class="selectProduct">
<select name="" value="">
<option selected="selected">Select Product You Want</option>
<option value="15000">Product RU Odin (15000 RUB.)</option>
<option value="17500">Product RU Dva (17500 RUB.)</option>
<option value="28400">Product RU Tri (28400 RUB.)</option>
<option value="32100">Product RU Chetire (32100 RUB.)</option>
</select> <span>×</span> <input type="text" name="" placeholder="QNTY" />
</div>

<div class="selectShippingMethod">
<input type="radio" name="selectShippingMethod" value="0" id="free" checked="checked" /> <label for="free">Free Shipping</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="selectShippingMethod" value="200" id="RussianPostOrdinary" /> <label for="RussianPostOrdinary">Russian Post Ordinary — 200 RUB.</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="selectShippingMethod" value="200" id="RussianPostFirstClass" /> <label for="RussianPostFirstClass">Russian Post First Class Shipping — 400 RUB.</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="selectShippingMethod" value="900" id="MoscowTransportCompany" /> <label for="MoscowTransportCompany">Moscow Transport Company — 900 RUB.</label>
</div>

<div class="total">Total: 0 RUB.</div>

</form>

</div>
```

How to make that calculator work? Total sum (0 RUB.) has to change depending on selections...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please dont start coding a shop if youre a newbie. There are a lot of Shopping systems out there ( like Magento ), so youre safe against the most common attack techniques (like SQLinjection etc) and you wont do it just with JS, you also at least need MySql...

Comment: Man, I know I will need PHP and bla-bla. In this step I just need this calculator. I will do others things then. Don't worry about my safety. I know what I am doing, believe me :) So, do you have anything to write about what I need? :)

Comment: at first: you dont know what youre doing, believe me ;) , and asking for code is not accepted in this forum. Ive just answered because im very friendly today....

Comment: You are very stupid then if you are saying things about a person who you don't know. You DO NOT know what I am doing. I will do other fields of the form myself, in this step I just want summing to work. You just don't want to understand me, maybe just because you think you are the best one and others are freaks... You are older than me, but the way you act here looks like you are freak yourself :)))

Comment: You could just skip this question. Why did you come here then? You waste your time and you don't help and I am not helped...

Answer (score 0):

Using http://jquery.org:

```
$('#ProductSelect').change(function(){
var total=0;
$('input:checked').each(function(){
    total+=this.val();
  });
 $("#total").val(total);
});
```

Expecting the select to have the id "ProductSelect" and total to be an id.

Comment: @ExSraightDavid nope. Learn it yourself. Dig trough the docs and you will get it working by yourself...

Comment: Then you could just skip this question. You DID NOT help me. You are just wasting your time, because really, your answer was not usefull for me. You started, but didn't finish :)